# Inline if within array - unexpected "=>"

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to run an if statement inside of an array. The array is used to update a database table row. However I have a couple of questions regarding this.

1)

I get the error `syntax error, unexpected '=>'` when doing something similar to the below:

```
[
   'column1' => 'some data',
   ($var === true ? 'column2' => 'another column', : '')
]
```

So if this can work using the =>, my other question is:

2)

If `$var === false`, then won't this fail too because it will be trying to insert `''` into the array? Not too sure on this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't write conditions like that while initialising the array - you can instead:

```
$array = [
  'column1' => 'some data'
];

$var === true && $array['column2'] = 'another column';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = array(
   'column1' => 'some data',
)

if($var === true) 
   $array['column2'] = 'another column';
```

Answer (score 0):

not possible to do? :

```
if($var === true) $array['column2'] = 'another column';
```

Or

```
'column2' => ($var === true) ? 'another column' : '',
```

Never tried your way, or seen it. But maybe someone else knows.